# python regex match everything between defined word on the beginning of the line to defined word in other line

Tags: python, regex, pattern-matching

I have file like the below, it's part of the config which contains references for ruledefs (i.e. rd-6). Config file structure always looks the same except the rulebase and ruledefs names.
This part is rulebase-definition (for this purpose of this question this is also my RB-definitions.txt)

```
##Rulebase-definition  
rulebase bb
      action priority 6 dynamic-only ruledef rd-6 charging-action throttle monitoring-key 1
      action priority 7 dynamic-only ruledef rd-7 charging-action p2p_Drop
      action priority 139 dynamic-only ruledef rd-8 charging-action p2p_Drop monitoring-key 1
#exit
```

Here is the ruledef-definition example (also this is the output I'm looking for in this rising this question)

```
##Ruledef-definition
ruledef rd-8
          ip server-ip-address range host-pool BB10_RIM_1
          ip server-ip-address range host-pool BB10_RIM_2
#exit
ruledef rd-3
          ip any-match = TRUE
#exit
```

I was able to match specyfic rulebase name (with rulebase definition) given by raw_input(), and save it to the file RB-definitions.txt as you can see it above.
Also I was able to match ruledef names(but only names) from RB-definitions.txt and store it in ruledef_list with the below

```
RDFile = open('RB-definitions.txt')
txt2 = RDFile.read()
ruledef_list = []
for match2 in re.findall((?<=ruledef)((?:.|\n)*?)(?=charging-action), txt2):
    print match2 +"\n" 
    ruledef_list.append(match2)
```

But I keep failing when I have to match specific ruledef from ruledef-defitnition as shown above.
ruledef word is always first in the line

```
start_tag =    '^ruledef ' #additional space char
content = '((?:.|\n)*?)'                                
end_tag = '#exit'

for RD_name in ruledef_list:
 print RD_name
 for match in re.findall(start_tag + RD_name + content + end_tag, txt):
    print match + end_tag + "\n"
```

I tried with '^ruledef ', '^ruledef\s+' or even '([ruledef ])\b', but none of this is working.
I Have to mathc the first word, because if not I will match also part from rulebase-defitnition which starts from "ruledef".

How I can match everything between defined first word in the line to next "#exit"?
So as output I could get the below

```
ruledef rd-8
      ip server-ip-address range host-pool BB10_RIM_1
      ip server-ip-address range host-pool BB10_RIM_2
#exit
ruledef rd-3
      ip any-match = TRUE
#exit
```

For better understanding please find the whole script with example config here http://pastebin.com/q3VUeAdh

Answer (score 2):

You are missing multiline mode. Otherwise `^` matches only at the beginning of the entire string. Also, you can avoid the `(?:.|\n)` by using the singleline/dotall mode (which makes `.` match *any*  character):

```
start_tag = r'^ruledef ' #additional space char
content = r'(.*?)'                                
end_tag = r'#exit'

...

for match in re.findall(start_tag + RD_name + content + end_tag, txt, re.M|re.S):
    ...
```

Note that this will give you the contents of the `ruledef` (i.e. just the things that were matched by the `content` part - no `ruledef`, no name, no `#exit). If this is not what you want, simply remove the parentheses in`content`:

```
...
content = r'.*?'
...
```

By the way, it *might* be more efficient to use a negative lookahead instead of an ungreedy quantifier (but it doesn't have to - please profile this, if speed is an important concern for you):

```
...
content = r'(?:(?!#exit).)*'
...
```

Finally, note how I use raw strings for all regex patterns. This is just good practice in Python - otherwise you might get problems with complex escape patterns (i.e., you'll have to double-escape some things).

Comment: +1 This is the right idea. Based on the OP's desired output (and extra printing logic), I think the capturing parentheses should go around everything from "ruledef" through "#exit". Also, the example data appears(?) to show optional leading spaces in front of the "ruledef" lines.

Comment: Thank you for your inputs, I've checked what you recomend it but still no output.
As to the optional spaces leading the "ruledef" was my bad, something had happened when copy&pasting and creating this thread. Sorry if this was misleading.

As to desired output if it will be just matched it will have this kind of output.
I'm trying to do such script because the config files I work with for ruledef and rulebases are often 10+k lines long, which makes cuting out i.e. 5 rulebases with all coresponding ruledefs and their definitions a dull job.

Comment: @bart-barton sorry, could you please clarify what exactly is not working as expected?

Comment: @m.buettner yes of course. There is no output. After changes proposed by you, "print match + end_tag + "\n"" doesn't show anything.

Comment: @bart-barton it does work for me. are you sure there are no spaces in front of `ruledef` in the line in question?

Comment: @m.buettner, Yes, there are no leading spaces, double checked it. When I do the proposed in separate file (on entire config) it works, but I'm getting all the `ruledefs` not only those present in `rulebase` definition I was able to copy to `RB-definition.txt` file. For better understanding, here is the link to whole script with dummy config on the bottom. [link](http://pastebin.com/q3VUeAdh)